# Unable to post the image,link to facebook from iOS Application

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, xcode7

while posting, it is giving an error like "your message couldn't be sent because it includes content that other people on Facebook have reported as abusive" this thing is happening from today it self. Before it is worked fine with same code. I tried to resolve but no luck.

Can any body help me to resolve this thing!

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKIWa.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [appeal form](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/244560538958131) for blocked content.

What is the url that you are trying to share?